# use jquery to find active element and next 3 elements

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I'm trying to use jquery to find the active slide (class name = swiper-slide-active), and then include the next 3 elements to put some CSS code on them.

HTML:

```
<div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active">...</div> ## use jquery to find this class
<div class="swiper-slide">...</div> ## and this one
<div class="swiper-slide">...</div> ## and this one
<div class="swiper-slide">...</div> ## and this one
<div class="swiper-slide">...</div> ## not this
<div class="swiper-slide">...</div> ## not this
<div class="swiper-slide">...</div> ## not this
<div class="swiper-slide">...</div> ## not this
<div class="swiper-slide">...</div> ## not this
```

I've tried the following:

```
$('.swiper-slide-active').css({opacity:.5}).next('.swiper-slide:lt(3)').css({opacity:.5});
```

But it doesn't work, I've also tried this:

```
$('.swiper-slide-active').slice(0,3).css({opacity:.5});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and the apply `.slice(0, 3`.

```js
$('.swiper-slide-active').nextAll().slice(0, 3).css({
  opacity: .5
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active">## use jquery to find this class</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">## and this one</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">## and this one</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">## and this one</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">##</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">##</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">##</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">##</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">##</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">##</div>
```